# Redshift scale up not possible via Elastic Resize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I was trying to resize my Redshift Cluster via `Elastic Resizing` from 8 to 16 nodes **RA3.XPLUS** via console but that wasn't an available option.

Why is that the case? I was under the impression that elastic resize is possible as long as doubling or halving number of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Because I already did a resizing in the past by doubling the number of **RA3.XPLUS** nodes from 4 to 8, it's not possible to do this operation "multiple times".

Which means if my initial configuration was 4 nodes I can go at most to 8 via `Elastic Resizing`, not any further. Otherwise might be required to go with `Classic Resizing`.

From documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-cluster-operations.html

> With some ra3 node types, you can increase the number of nodes up to four times the existing count. Specifically, suppose that your cluster consists of ra3.4xlarge or ra3.16xlarge nodes. You can then use elastic resize to increase the number of nodes in an 8-node cluster to 32. Or you can pick a value below the limit. (Keep in mind that the ability to grow the cluster by 4x depends on the source cluster size.) If your cluster has ra3.xlplus nodes, the limit is double.

Another valid alternative to scale up via `Elastic Resize` is to change node types (e.g. **RA3.4XLARGE**).